# How to fix an error on interface when implementing IQueueServices in Azure-bus-services?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-queues

I have the following error on my Interface implementation;

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

namespace ServiceBusApplication
{
    public class AzBus : IQueueService
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public string QueueName { get; set; }
        private static IQueueClient queueClient;
        public void Send(string payload)
        {
            queueClient = new QueueClient(ConnectionString, QueueName);
            var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));
            queueClient.SendAsync(message).Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

The error is on creating service client queueClient = new QueueClient();
and when sendAsync(message).Wait();

While my IQueService interface is as follows;

```
using System;

namespace ServiceBusApplication
{
    public interface IQueueService
    {
        void Send(string payload);
        string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        string QueueName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What am missing exactly here? i cant seem to solve this issue. All of my assemblies are installed via NuGet package on Visual Studio 2019. Please assist me team, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try async and await. Rather than putting void and wait(), try the below option

Interface:

```
using System;

namespace ServiceBusApplication
{
    public interface IQueueService
    {
        Task Send(string payload);
        string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        string QueueName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Class :

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

namespace ServiceBusApplication
{
    public class AzBus : IQueueService
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public string QueueName { get; set; }
        private static IQueueClient queueClient;
        public Task Send(string payload)
        {
            queueClient = new QueueClient(ConnectionString, QueueName);
            var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));
           await queueClient.SendAsync(message);
        }
    }
}
```

This error would be because of the asynchronous function call. Just try this one and comment you still get the error